# Is there an option to "Sign in with Facebook" on Foursquare embedded webview?

Tags: facebook, foursquare

I know there is a way to sign into Foursquare with Facebook on Foursquare.com. Currently, I am building a mobile app which requires singing into Foursquare. However, when Foursquare embedded webview inside my app is displayed, I don't see the option to sign in with Facebook. This is a total bummer.